# How to have button as signal and table as slot in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qobject, qt-signals

I know the very basic of Qt. The only thing I need is a button and a table. When the user presses the button, I fill the table in with data which comes from database. I have already figured out the database part, mostly.

Now my main problem is Qt signals and slots. In Java, we do it by events and handlers. How can I connect my button to an update of the table. Or if it is better, I could update the table when programs run.

Any sample code or reference where I can find the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very ismple. You would use [Qt signal slot mechanism](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) for this. You need to connect [the button's clicked signal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) to your update handler slot for the database.

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QPushButton>

...

class UpdateHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    explicit UpdateHandler(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
    {
        connect(&m_pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), SLOT(updateDatabase()));
    }

    public slots:
    void updateDatabase()
    {
        // update the database here.
    }
    private:
        QPushButton m_pushButton;
};
```

With C++11 support, this would be even simpler as you could use lambda.

```
    UpdateHandler::UpdateHandler(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
    {
        connect(&m_pushButton , &QPushButton::clicked,  [&] {
            // update the database here
        }};
    }
```

Disclaimer: this is just proto type code, so this was not even compilation-tested, but it should get you going, I think.

Here is a good example how to create signals and slots using QtCreator:

[Creating a Qt Widget Based Application](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.1/creator-writing-program.html)

[image]

Here you can find the all Qt 4.8 documentation for that if you still happen to use that:

[Qt Designer's Signals and Slots Editing Mode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-connection-mode.html)

[image]

Comment: I have watched couple youtube video but in qt4 when I right click there is no option which say go to slot and when I click on edit slot and click on button does not work for me :(